# How to encode '%' in request param

Tags: java, spring, urlencode, http-request-parameters

I want to pass request parameter in spring API as

```
%3 ST%
```

I send this request via postman like

```
%253 ST%
```

This works as expected. The problem is that I need to pass this from one microservice to another via REST API. Both applications are built on Spring framework. When I construct this url as string as

```
localhost:port/api/version/search?address=%253ST%25
```

The other microservice endpoint couldn't decode and throws exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "3 "
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:194)
    at io.undertow.util.QueryParameterUtils.decodeParam(QueryParameterUtils.java:134)
    at io.undertow.util.QueryParameterUtils.handleQueryParameter(QueryParameterUtils.java:118)
    at io.undertow.util.QueryParameterUtils.parseQueryString(QueryParameterUtils.java:106)
    at io.undertow.util.QueryParameterUtils.mergeQueryParametersWithNewQueryString(QueryParameterUtils.java:151)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:205)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:150)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:112)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
```

I am calling the service as

```
String searchQuery = "%" + searchAddress + "%";
            String uri = MessageFormat.format(GET_SERVICE_ADDRESSES, URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, "UTF-8"));
            Response response = rootWebTarget.path(uri).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header("Authorization", "AUTH_TOKEN").get();
```

I also tried to use URLEncoder to encode and then send this to API. When I encode that search string it looks like

```
%253+ST%25
or
%253%20ST%25
```

Both of these encode don't work.

Please help.

Comment: How do you call that other service, which you want to pass query param? Can you post that code?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that how I am calling the other service.

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, "UTF-8"), "UTF_8")` - a hack, as the second encode should have been done at forwarding. Also bypassing the HTTP REST protocol is often done.

Comment: What type is the rootWebTarget object? With resttemplate this should work without issues.

Comment: WebTarget rootWebTarget ... rootWebTarget represents javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the query parameter using the `queryParam` method.

If you submit your request using the code below, that should pass without issues.

```
  Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget rootWebTarget = client.target("localhost:port/api/version");
        rootWebTarget
                .queryParam("address", "%253ST%25") 
                .path("/search") 
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .get();
```

Your request will look like this `localhost:port/api/version/search?address=%253ST%25`

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
String encodedSuffix = URLEncoder.encode(suffix, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
```

And for suffix value `%3 ST%` I got the result `%253+ST%25` and when I send this as a url parameter I saw in debug in my rest controller it was successfully decoded as `%3 ST%`. So `UrlEncoder` works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue with the following changes. I am not sure if it's a hack or something but it's resolved.

```
            String searchQuery = "%25" + searchAddress + "%25";
            String uri = MessageFormat.format(GET_SERVICE_ADDRESSES, URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, "UTF-8"));
            Response response = rootWebTarget.path(uri).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header(HEADER, AUTH_HEADER_VALUE).get();
```